# Combine Multiple Regexp Patterns

Tags: regex, groovy

I've been a regex practitioner for years, mainly in perl, where you can do handy things like:

```
my $delim  = qr#[-\:/]#;                       # basic enough
my $field1 = qr/(\d{8})/;                      # basic enough
my $field2 = qr/(?:one|two|three)(\d{8,10})/;  # basic enough
...
my $re = qr/$field1${delim}$field2/;      # beautiful magicks
while (<>) { 
  /$re/ and print "$1\n";
}
```

The point is not that you can precompile them, it's that you can use one regex inside the other as a variable to build a bigger composite regex that is *actually readable*.  The individual pieces are testable w/ simple test data and the composite can be dynamic ($delim might be passed as an argument to a sub, for example).

The question is, how does one approach this in Java, where the Pattern/Matcher approach rules the day.

Here's my stab:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

Pattern delim  = Pattern.compile("[-\:/]");
Pattern field1 = Pattern.compile("(\d{8})");
Pattern field2 = Pattern.compile("(?:one|two|three)(\d{8,10})");
Pattern re_pat = Pattern.complle(
  field1.pattern() + delim.pattern() + field2.pattern();
)
...
Matcher re = re_pat.matcher(input);
```

Is this reliable (any gotchas?) and otherwise the best Java equivalent?  Also feel free to answer this relative to Groovy, since that is my ultimate destination for this code (but it seems Groovy more or less relies on the underlying Java regex implementations).  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example, I don't see any reason to precompile the regexes at all.  If I were doing it, I'd just define `delim`, `field1`, and `field2` as `String`s, and combine them.

Adding to that, Groovy does a good job of hiding the ugliness of Java's verbose regexes.  An example would look something like this:

```groovy
def delim  = /[-:\/]/
def field1 = /(\d{8})/
def field2 = /(?:one|two|three)(\d{8,10})/
def re_pat = /$field1${delim}$field2/

// optionally import Matcher and explicitly declare re
def re = input =~ re_pat
```

You shouldn't have to worry about compiling the regexes beforehand, as `Pattern` caches any regexes it's already compiled (if I remember correctly).  If you wanted to precompile the pattern, use this:

```groovy
def re_pat = ~/$field1${delim}$field2/
```

---

One thing to note here: the `/ /` delimiters in Groovy are really just `String`s (or `GStrings` if they contain variable references).  They aren't really regular expressions, but they have the convenience of not needing to double escape everything.

If you want to avoid escaping even `/`, then you can use [dollar-slashy-strings](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+1.8+release+notes#Groovy18releasenotes-Dollarslashystrings) in Groovy 1.8 and newer:

```groovy
def delim = $/[-:/]/$
```

I don't think that's necessary in your example, though.

Comment: I should have mentioned that [Groovy adds some awesome functionality to `Matcher`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), making it trivial to loop over the results or access them like an array (e.g. `re[0][1]` is the first group [1] from the first match [0] ).

Comment: It's a simplified example: the intent is to run against hundreds of millions of lines, so I don't mind precompiling for this case.  The groovy does look better, doesn't it?  Yours isn't far from my initial take (in groovy), so I'll take that as confirmation.  Thanks for the pointers on quoting and stringiness.